# Hibernate:Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-server-2008-r2

I am new to hibernate, I now how to connect Local DB from hiibenate.cfg ,but now I want to access DB which is not local??
how can I can any one help me??

Comment: Just use remote database connection url instead of local connection. And Bingo..!!

Comment: @vbera can u plz explain in detail or provide any reference site??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the connection url property in config file to your remote database url.

For ex :

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test 
</property>
```

This will used to connect local test db. Now change it to something like :

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
  jdbc:mysql://192.168.12.35:3306/test
</property>
```

This will connect to remote database `test` which is running on 192.168.12.35 ip.

Answer (score 0):

change the property name hibernate.connection.url from local to your desired database IP address  like this:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
  jdbc:mysql://192.168.12.35:3306/test
</property>
```